# How to count rows in SSIS based on specific conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008 like below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure
        @Id int,
        @hin varchar(30),
        @checkValue varchar(30),
        @CounterDeceasedPatients int=0 OUTPUT

insert into myTable
values (@Id, @hin, GETDATE())

if (@checkValue is not null)
BEGIN
    set @CounterDeceasedPatients = @CounterDeceasedPatients + 1;
    update myTable
    set hin= @checkValue
    where Id = @Id

RETURN;
END
```

I am calling this SP via SSIS, by using an OLE DB Command in Data Flow, which enables each rows in my file go to the SP - with the sql command: `EXEC [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] ?,?,?`. (The order of data (?) in my file is: `Id, hin, checkValue`)

What I want to do is to count how many different records (different rows) entered the if condition in my SP. SO I believe need to place a "row counter" somewhere, filtering its usage where @checkValue is not null. But I couldnt find it how. I am a newbie in SSIS, so I appreciate if someone helps me to figure this out. Thanks.

EDIT: I am trying to select only @checkValue as an input parameter for my ROW COUNT, but it is giving error:
[image]

EDIT2: I updated my SP. I added "CounterDeceasedPatients" variable as Int32 in SSIS and assigned it to 0. My sql execute command is: `EXEC [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] ?,?,?,?,CounterDeceasedPatients`

This is giving me the error:

> Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult:
>   0x80040E07  Description: "Error converting data type nvarchar to
>   int.".

When I use `EXEC [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] ?,?,?,?,CounterDeceasedPatients output` as SQL command, then I receive the error:

> Description: "Cannot use the OUTPUT option when passing a constant to
>   a stored procedure.

I need help.

Comment: Have you heard for [`Row Count Transformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141136.aspx) in SSIS ?

Comment: Yes, I read this page: http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-use-row-count.html

But I couldnt manage Row Count working, and couldnt see where to filter it.

Comment: Add an SSIS variable `@rowcount`. Initialise it to 0. Create an output parameter in your stored procedure and modify your stored procedure so it adds one to it inside the `if`. Map your SSIS variable to that output parameter so each call it passes in the value that was potentially modified in previous calls.

Comment: I updated my question based on ur comments Martin. I appreciate if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script transformation and a DataFlow-level package variable.

Create the int-type variable with a default of 0, and in the script transformation, increment the variable if `checkvalue` is not null for the incoming row, and then use the value of the variable to set the value of your counter column.

Note that I am suggesting this INSTEAD of trying to update the counter with an OUTPUT variable in your stored procedure, and not as a way of trying to get that idea to work.